# need a concrete example about when robust buffer access effective

Tags: opengl-es

In(KHR_robustness.txt), having such a passage:
When enabled(robust buffer accsee), indices within the element array that reference vertex data that lies outside the enabled attribute’s vertex buffer object
[for OpenGL ES] result in undefined values
[for OpenGL] result in reading zero
for the corresponding attributes, but cannot result in application failure.

I couldn't know under what circumstances robust buffer access will work(if it was already enabled)?

I try to change the indices[]. Let it index out of array bound.
But regardless of whether I enable robust buffer access or not, the result of draw is to replace the wrong index point with (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) point.And both do not result in application failure.

## The original code

```
vertexArray[ ]={
-0.5,0.5,0.0,1.0,
-1.0,0.5,0.0,1.0,
-0.5,0.0,0.0,1.0,
-0.5,1.0,0.0,1.0,
}
indices[ ]={
0,1,2
1,2,3,
}
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,12,GL_UNSINGED_SHORT,0);
```

## The modify code

```
vertexArray[ ]={
-0.5,0.5,0.0,1.0,
-1.0,0.5,0.0,1.0,
-0.5,0.0,0.0,1.0,
-0.5,1.0,0.0,1.0,
}
indices[ ]={
0,1,2
1,2,4,
}
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,12,GL_UNSINGED_SHORT,0);
```

//indices[6]=4, while vertexArray[4] is out of this array, I thought in this case, out of buffer access happened.(Is it right?)

Comment: *"`vertexArray[4]` is out of this array,... in this case, out of buffer access happened..."* - Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

> But regardless of whether I enable robust buffer access or not, the
>   result of draw is to replace the wrong index point with
>   (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) point. And both do not result in application
>   failure.

Without the extension enabled the behavior of an out-of-bounds access is implementation defined. It might access outside the array, it might crash, it might replace the out-of-bounds data with a constant value, it might clamp the access to the extents of the buffer. It might choose which of these unpredictably and inconsistently, so an application cannot safely rely on anything.

The wording of the specification is that the extension must:

> Provide an enable to guarantee that out-of-bounds buffer object
>   accesses by the GPU will have deterministic behavior and preclude
>   application instability or termination due to an incorrect buffer
>   access.

I.e. it's not allowed to crash, but any of the other behaviors in the earlier list are OK as long as they are consistently applied.

In summary; the behavior you are seeing is valid for both of these scenarios but note that other platforms may give a different result.

Comment: Thanks, I konw exactly what undefind means now. And you said diff platforms may give a diif result. this reminds me, I guess this is the reason why I have that situation. I will try to pass a uniform data to shader and achieve the  out of bounds buffer. Thanks again!